# C# WaitHandle.WaitAll() is always waiting

Tags: c#

Following is my code , the wait all method is always waiting .

```
  class Program
    {
        static StreamWriter _fileStream;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _fileStream = File.CreateText(@"C:\Praveen\HelloThread.txt");
            List<ManualResetEvent> meList = new List<ManualResetEvent>();
            ManualResetEvent currentEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true);
            ManualResetEvent nextEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            meList.Add(currentEvent);
            int length = 10;
            Data data = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Writing started...");
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                data = new Data { CurrentEvent = currentEvent, Number = i, NextEvent = nextEvent };
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(PrintMsg, data);
                meList.Add(nextEvent);
                currentEvent = nextEvent;
                nextEvent = nextEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            }

            CloseAll(meList);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void CloseAll(List<ManualResetEvent> meList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Requested to close all...");
            while (WaitHandle.WaitAll(meList.ToArray()))
            {

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done with the writing...");
        }

        private static void PrintMsg(object state)
        {

            Data data = state as Data;

            data.CurrentEvent.WaitOne();

            string msg = "Hello times...";
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                _fileStream.WriteLine(msg + data.Number);
                Console.WriteLine(msg + data.Number);
            }           
            data.NextEvent.Set();
        }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public ManualResetEvent CurrentEvent { get; set; }
        public ManualResetEvent NextEvent { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }
```

What's going on , why it's always waiting , any idea ?

Comment: When I see code like this nextEvent = nextEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false); I tend to think the author has not really looked at their own code too hard. It is unclear what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: What is the ultimate goal with this? You are launching threads but serializing their work, this looks more like Producer-Consumer where you could have a single worker thread and use a ConcurrentQueue to store your work items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an infinite loop in your `CloseAll` method. [WaitAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) returns `true` when all events are signaled. You do not need the empty while loop, just add the line:

```
WaitHandle.WaitAll(meList.ToArray());
```